# ASP.net save dropdown-list Selected-Item as a session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to save the selected item of a **drop down list** as a session but I am always getting the first result from the locations table.

ASP.net:

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

C# (just getting the locations to the drop down list is working fine)

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select location_id, location_name from locations", con);

    con.Open();
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "location_name";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "location_id";
    DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

The problem: always retrieving the first location from the db.

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string location;
    Session["userLocation"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
    location = Session["userLocation"].ToString();
}
```

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Most likely that because you Bind in pageload

Comment: Sounds like you are right.

Comment: how can i bind that not on pageload ?

Comment: I prefer using ObjectDataSource, SqlDataSource and other and never have your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the binding only if `Page.IsPostBack` equals `False`.

The reason might be that your data operation for filling the `DropDownList1` is called every time the page is requested. It is also possible that this data retrieval happens before `btnGo_Click` is executed and as a result the `SelectedIndex` will reset to 0 which is the first location in your case.

Comment: This one still catches me, solved my issue too! In my case the dropdownlist was a user control placed inside another detailsview user control using Master pages - but the rule still applies.